# Keeping track of non registered user in a django website

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, anonymous-users

I'm making a django website and want to keep record of the people who didn't registered in my website like what all they searched in my website and all.For that what should I do to get all that information??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the tab for autocomplete for input tag